# How to align JavaScript variables from comma in PhpStorm?

Tags: javascript, syntax, phpstorm

Before raising your finger and shoot "that's duplicate !", read carefully.
I checked in the options of PhpStorm editor, and i am not trying to do that :

```
var myVar           = 1;
var anotherGreatVar = 2;
```

or

```
var myVar           = 1
,anotherGreatVar    = 2;
```

What I am trying to do is :

```
var myVar           = 1
    ,anotherGreatVar = 2;
```

I don't care to have the variables' values aligned, what I want is the variables' names to be aligned. I really like this syntax but PhpStorm seems not to have that particular option to set, or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it has a source format option. Like Aptana.

I'm not sure why you want the comma before second instead after the first:

```
var var1 = "something", 
    var2 = "someother"
```